# Throw object instead of returning string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

How to build an Error object instead of give its a string? https://codesandbox.io/s/pwr973487x

```
async function getUrl()  {
  try {

    const res = await axios.get('https://httpstat.us/500')
  } catch(e) {
    const errorObj = {
      status: 500,
      message: 'Internal server error, something is not defined etc'
    }
    throw new Error('err') //how to build object?
  }
}
```

I want `throw Error()` to return `errorObj`. Do I have to do my own class to do that or I can modify the existing Error class for that? I need that so it standardize my error message of my different set of Apis.

Comment: You can just throw `errorObj`...? - Also, why are you throwing inside a catch?

Comment: @why not throw in a catch?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - I normally don't, unless I expect to catch the error elsewhere... but you can definitely just throw a plain object without extending the Error object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the error object returned from catch

```
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('https://httpstat.us/500')
  } catch(e) {
    e.message = 'Internal server error, something is not defined etc';
    throw e;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try with [the `cause` propoty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) of :

> TS has inaccurate value type about it at present, [this is being discussed on the official to revolve it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48098).

```
try {
     throw new Error('Failed in some way', { 
       cause: {status: 400} 
     });
} catch(e) {
     console.log(e); // Error('Failed in some way')
     console.log(e.cause) // {status: 400} 
}
```

or throw the Error instance with the custom property

```
try {
     const error = new Error('Failed in some way');
     error.status = 400;
     throw error;
   } catch(e) {
     console.log(e); // Error('Failed in some way')
     console.log(e.status) // 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a field to the Error object, e.g.

```
var err = new Error('Internal Server error');
err.customField = { someProperty: 'some value'};

console.log(err);
```

And then you can throw it as normal:

```
throw err;
```

When you catch the error (higher up in the call stack) you can pull out the custom field:

```
try
{
    throw err;
}
catch (e)
{
   console.error(e);
   console.log(e.customField);
}
```

With ES6 onwards you can also create your own error class:

```
class MyError extends Error {

    constructor(message, customValue) {
        super(message);
        this.field = customValue;
    }

    get customField() {
        return this.field;
    }

    set customField(obj) {
        this.field = obj;
    }
};

var ex = new MyError('Error message', {someProperty: 'some value'});
console.dir(ex);
console.log('My custom error details: ', ex.customField);
```

Comment: You can also use `console.warn('something')`, or `console.error('something')` to have them looking different in your 
browser's console.

Comment: What's the preference to extend the Error object when one can throw any object they like.

Comment: Good point, @evolutionxbox, you can go with that approach. I'm not sure all browsers will play as nice with this pattern, e.g. how it will be reported in the console etc. I'd personally feel more comfortable extending the error object.

Comment: Also, will you get a stack trace with any object?